# Fallback font with iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to create PDF:s. I have a small problem that some glyphs are missing from some of the fonts the user can use. Is it possible to have a fallback font or a font stack like you do in CSS?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the FontSelector class.

There's a Java example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=214) and a C# example [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/FontSelectionExample.cs).

The idea is to create a `FontSelector` object to which you add fonts with the `AddFont()` method. Now when you have a `string` that contains glyphs that are missing in one font, but present in another font, you can use the `process()` method to create a `Phrase` that consists of a series of `Chunk` objects that use different fonts.

The order in which you add the fonts to the selector is important. When examining the characters inside a `string`, the first font will be examined for the presence of a glyph that corresponds with a character. If a glyph is found, that font will be used for that character; if a glyph is missing, the second font will be examined. The same glyph can be present in different fonts, but iText will always look at the first font added to the selector first and will ignore all the other fonts as soon as a glyph is found.